# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: adding a window to a container

Tags: java, jframe

I get 'java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: adding a window to a container' when I call frame.add(this). What am I doing wrong, and how do I fix the error. Thanks in advance.

```
public class mainclass extends JFrame{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private int width = 400;
private int height = 400;

public static JFrame frame;

public static void main(String args[]) {
frame = new JFrame();

    mainclass mainclass = new mainclass();
    mainclass.createFrame();
}

public void createFrame() {
    frame.setSize(new Dimension(width, height));
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.add(this); // this is where the error occurs
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setIconImage(new ImageIcon("res/icon.png").getImage());
}
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: adding a window to a container
at java.awt.Container.checkNotAWindow(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.add(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JFrame.addImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.add(Unknown Source)
at test.mainclass.createFrame(mainclass.java:27)
at test.mainclass.main(mainclass.java:21)
```

Comment: @Issac it will be helpful if you can post the stacktrace

Comment: You are adding a frame on to another frame. Please don't do it. What you want to achieve by this?

Comment: @Sanjeev I want to create a frame and then draw on it, and to draw on a frame you have to add something to it I believe...

Comment: `frame` is of type `JFrame`.
You're adding a `JFrame` to a `JFrame`.. This make no sense.

Comment: Yup you can use JPanel for that

Comment: @Sanjeev I now cannot seem to draw on the screen - `Image screen = createVoltaileImage(width, height); Graphics g = screen.getGraphics(); render(screen, g); private void render(Image screen, Graphics g) { g.setColor(Color.black) g.fillRect(0, 0, width, height); g.drawImage(screen, 0, 0, null); g.dispose();}`

Comment: Are you trying to display an image on your frame?

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is that you can't do this. Your question would benefit from describing *why* you would want to do this - what end result are you trying to achieve?

If you're trying to add another container then you should use [`JPanel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/panel.html)s. If you are trying to create an MDI-like app, then you should look at [`JInternalFrame`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html)s. If you want a popup frame, you need [`JDialog`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)s.

For a little more information, `JFrame`s are designed to be top-level containers - they contain a `JRootPane` as its only child. When you want to add something to a frame you are in effect adding to the frame's root pane, referred to as the *content pane*. The correct way is to call `frame.getContentPane().add()`.

This was a constant source of frustration because a lot of developers instinctively wanted to call `frame.add()` which is how practically all the other Swing components work. Therefore as a convenience `frame.add()` has been overridden to call `frame.getContentPane().add()`.

So if you think about what's happen in your example now, you are trying to add a JFrame to a frame's root content pane. Understandably root panes cannot have other top-level containers as child elements, eg JFrames as they possess their own root pane.

Answer (score 0):

`mainclass` extends from `JFrame`.  You can not a window to a container, that's just the way it is.

Try making `mainclass` extend from something like `JPanel` instead.

I'm also concerned about `new ImageIcon("res/icon.png")`.  This looks very much like the `icon.png` is an embedded resource rather than a file on the file system.  You may find you need to use `new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/res/icon.png"))` instead, but I don't have enough context to 100% sure